# how can i move a way from a dataGridView cell even when the cell value has not passed validation?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I am validating cell values in an unbound dataGridView control but am not liking the behaviour am getting.

When an invalid value is entered in the cell, i cant move away from that cell, am fine with that. When i clear the invalid data from the cell and leave it blank or empty, i still cant move away from the cell and am not liking that. Even when i press Escape key to undo the invalid data i had typed in the cell, am not able to move to any other cell in the dataGridView before entering a valid value in that particular cell. This means i am not able to cancel the entry of a row for example whose single columns value is missing.

To move away from the cell, i have to type atleast a 0(zero) but i don't want to be doing this, i want to be able to say ok, let me just arbort entering this whole record, or reset the cell value to empty, highlight it, move to another cell and then come back to it later.

```
private void dataGridViewSales_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
            {
                switch (this.dataGridViewSales.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
                {   
                    case "Qty":
                        {
                            decimal qty;

                            if (!decimal.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out qty))
                            {
                                e.Cancel = true;
                                this.dataGridViewSales.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "The quantity sold must be a numeric value";
                                dataGridViewSales.EditingControl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Well when you have blank its still executing your parse and it fails and hence its still there as `e.Cancel` is set to `true`. You will have to handle the empty case separately and set `e.Cancel=false` for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()) &&
    !decimal.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out qty))
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks, did it this way

```
if (this.dataGridViewSales.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow || string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
    {
    return;
    }
    else
    {
    e.Cancel = true;
    }
```